# Is there anyway to Disable or remove Shared Link for particular user in SharePoint Online using Rest API, CSOM or PNP

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, csom, pnp

I am looking for some mechanism to remove a specific user from a ShareLink in SharePoint Online via Rest API, CSOM or PNP, whilst leaving the ShareLink active and available for other users.

I want to replicate the functionality thats available via the UI below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using CSOM:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
                {
                    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Admin, password);
                    //get all list items
                    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
                    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    ctx.Load(listItems);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    //get the user
                    User RemoveUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(username);

                    //get the list item
                    ListItem listItem = listItems.FirstOrDefault(t => t.DisplayName == FileName);
                    ctx.Load(listItem, lt => lt.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, lt => lt.RoleAssignments.Include(p => p.Member, p => p.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(r => r.Name)));
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    //remove user
                    if(listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        foreach(RoleAssignment ra in listItem.RoleAssignments)
                        {
                            foreach(RoleDefinition rd in ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                string[] member = ra.Member.LoginName.Split('\\');
                                if (member.Length > 1)
                                {
                                    string m = member[1];

                                    if (username == m)
                                    {
                                        ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(rd);
                                        ra.Update();                                        
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```